# Xpath in Selenium IDE - Store attribute from image

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

The issue is I need to find an image with a certain class and get its source.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>xpath=(//div[@class='item']//img[@class='dealItem']/@src)[${i}]</td>
    <td>itemImage</td>
</tr>
```

Log: [error] Invalid xpath

Comment: What exactly do you need from the html? Can you elaborate please.

And what was the xpath that you used?

Comment: @BludShot, both of your questions are clearly answered in both title and description.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of the page itself please, specifically the area around the image you're trying to capture the attribute for, there's not much that can be answered based on what you've provided, as there is nothing to provide any alternatives from

Comment: try removing the slash between img and @src   xpath=(//div[@class='item']//img[@class='dealItem']@src)[${i}]